# WinForm C# Button Database Relationship

Tags: c#, database, winforms, visual-studio-2010, button

is it possible to have different insert statements executed at the sametime? when a button is clicked?

Because We Are Tasked to normalize the table so I've divided my tables to reach its 3rd normal form.

However I am having a problem when I am inserting data into the database using my c# winform application.

What I want when the user clicks the button "CONFIRMED" the data will be separately inserted into different tables. And I will just then combine those tables using a select statement.

Comment: you can't fire off three different functions or have three insert statements?

Comment: The only way you could possibly run them in "parrellel" is to thread your application and query the SQL Server instance on seperate threads. However, SQL will not like this and will prioritise your jobs, running them one-by-one anyway. With this in mind, the best way is to run the querys as Code Monkey has suggested, with three seperate `YourCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` requests.

Comment: Maybe you could add some sample code and the new normalized database that gives you trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to handle this would be using a stored procedure to do the actual inserting/updating (CRUD). It will help you separate your layers and make any changes inside your database transparent to your frontend application.

Comment: And i would suggest not to Mix WinForms with DataInsertion ,i think Data Insertion and Data Handling should be located at a Specific Class ,not at UI Class.

Comment: Unable to as the requirements change process would be months of work to get it approved. so I am stuck with using the bound datatable

Comment: @ThorBurfine Let me guess: The change request causing your programming dilemma was approved ad hoc but to justify any architectural change requires getting approval from *n* departments.

Answer (score -1):

Try with Parallel Programing by using Task Parallel Library (TPL)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/Parallel_Programming/NET4ParallelIntro.aspx

Comment: I'd say that's the proverbial sledgehammer. It will introduce problems with race conditions and violates [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).